# Jump to specific part of a method without losing its values

Tags: objective-c, xcode, goto

I have below senerio
Class aviewcontroller call a function

```
  [  -(void)methodA:(NSString*)parameter1 withParam:(NSString*)param2]
```

of NSObject type class functionClass where i have written my code, from aviewcontroller i am passing parameter in it.

What i want : `if my param2 == hello1` then inside functionClass a random number will generate and then it will call the same

```
   [ -(void)methodA:(NSString*)parameter1 withParam:(NSString*)param2]
```

function again

**//My main class aviewcontroller**

```
-(void)viewdidload
{

    functionClass *obj = [[functionClass alloc] init];
     [obj methodA:@"hello" withParam:@"Hello1"];
}
```

**//My class name: functionClass of type NSObject**

```
//Method A

-(void)methodA:(NSString*)parameter1 withParam:(NSString*)param2

{

//Label A

NSLog(@"value of parameter1 =%@", parameter1);
NSLog(@"value of param2 =%@", param2);
/
if([param2 isEqualtostring:@"hello1"])
   {

    NSString *newparamgenerate=[self generateRandomNumber];
    //here need to go to label A with replace parameter value of param2      with newparamgenerate and then execute the code in same flow;


    }


}



//method 2

-(NSString*) generateRandomNumber
 {

NSString*random=@"TESTRANDOM";

return random;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to repeat the code again once you have generated your number, you would simply need to re-invoke the method with the new parameter. You have an if statement there which will control the flow and prevent an infinite loop so there is no harm in this case of calling a method from within itself, as long as method `random` can't return 'hello1' which it can't.  Working code would look like this:

```
//Method A

-(void)methodA:(NSString*)parameter1 withParam:(NSString*)param2

{

//Label A

NSLog(@"value of parameter1 =%@", parameter1);
NSLog(@"value of param2 =%@", param2);
/
if([param2 isEqualtostring:@"hello1"])
   {

    NSString *newparamgenerate=[self generateRandomNumber];
    [self methodA: @"hello" withParam: newparamgenerate];
    return
    //here need to go to label A with replace parameter value of param2      with newparamgenerate and then execute the code in same flow;


    }


}



//method 2

-(NSString*) generateRandomNumber
 {

NSString*random=@"TESTRANDOM";

return random;
}
```

The formatting of your code is a little questionable in places so I would advise you to research and take on board Objective-C formatting best practices.

Comment: thanks jacob, actually its a senerio of one of my client's requirement.|